# How to get exact colors in OpenGL Android?

Tags: android, colors, opengl-es, color-space

It looks like that OpenGL applies some color space transformation:

Rendering, glReadPixels , expected

```
(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25), ( 56, 57, 59, 64), ( 64, 64, 64, 64)<br>
(0.50,0.50,0.50,0.50), (112,114,118,128), (128,128,128,128)<br>
(0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75), (168,171,178,191), (191,191,191,191)<br>
(1.00,1.00,1.00,1.00), (224,228,237,255), (255,255,255,255)<br>
```

I get the same if I pass colors as bytes e.g. `( 64, 64, 64, 64)` produces  `( 56, 57, 59, 64)` and so on...

Lighting is disabled, dithering is disabled

It's obviously some color component blending transformation, some kind of color temperature correction and it totally screws all up.

Does anybody know what is happening, and how to disable this color transformation?

Note: It's not glReadPixels problem, it's actually rendering - white object rendered on white surface isn't white on screen, it's a little darker... Why!?

**Update:**
So it came down to GLUtils.texImage2D(....)
If I don't call this - white is white.
If I do, even on another object rendering of which is commented out, this call applies some color transformation to entire Gl context

So what does GLUtils.texImage2D do to colors and how to avoid this?

**Mystery solved**
It all was just about disabling texturing for objects that are not supposed to be textured...

Answer (score 0):

`glReadPixels()` is affected by `glPixelStore()`, `glPixelTransfer()` and `glPixelMap()`.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml

Comment: I read it, there is something different though...
glReadPixels() gets me exactly (255,255,255) if I clear surface using that color, but it reads (224,228,237) if I render object having (255,255,255) in all vertices.
It's not just glReadPixels, it's actually rendering: when I render white object after clearing surface with white color I can see the object because it's actually drawn by color a little darker than white...
And the question is why, why, why the hell white object isn't white.